# Why place a hand on the Bible instead of the Judge's genitals when taking an oath?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Etymonline gives the etymology of [*testify*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=testify) as

> ...from testis "a witness".. + root of facere "to make"... Biblical sense of "openly profess one's faith and devotion" is attested from 1520s. Related: Testified; testifying; testification. (also, testament, intestate, etc.)

In Biblical times, to swear a most sacred oath, the swearer made his oath by holding on to the oath-giver's genitals.

> Abraham... said to the senior servant in his household...**Put your hand under my thigh. I want you to swear by the Lord**... that you will not get a wife for my son from the daughters of the Canaanites... So the servant **put his hand under the thigh of his master** Abraham and swore... (Gen. 24)

and

> When the time drew near for Israel *(Jacob)* to die, he called... Joseph and said to him, **“...put your hand under my thigh and promise that you will... not bury me in Egypt..."** Then Joseph swore to him, and Israel worshiped as he leaned *on the top of his staff*. (Gen. 47)

Rabbi Shlomo Itzhaki (aka Rashi) explains in his commentary:

> Since one (a Jew) who swears must take with his hand an article related to a mitzvah... and circumcision was his [Abraham's] first mitzvah, and he had fulfilled it with pain, **[Abraham's circumcised penis]** was dear to him; so he took it. (*bracketed expansions mine*)

[Others](http://taylormarshall.com/2008/10/testimony-and-testicles-oath-of.html) interpret (reason?) that this oath was sworn by holding the oath-giver's **testicles**.

The Latin word for "witness, one who attests" is ***testis***, as well as [*testicles*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=testicle&searchmode=none) (from Latin testiculus, diminutive of testis). The Greek for spermaria is similarly derived.

So, how did *testify, testimony, testament, protest, detest, contest,* even Old and New **Testament** diverge so wildly from it's origins, to swear while holding someone's penis or *testicles*? Why don't we swear *by our balls, soft bits, tallywags, twiddle-diddles, goolies, trinkets, bollocks, nuts, or cojones*?

Was there ever a time when such little things didn't make such big promises?

Comment: I can't put my finger on it, but something about this question seems backwards. Also, the part of the question asked in the title seems answered in the question itself: there have always been other things to swear on besides balls, like the aforementioned scrolls.

Comment: "Un testo sacro" is not *a holy ball* :) but *a holy text*, so to testify, I'd imagine would be closer linked to the expression of something written and being sacred. Still, I liked the question and the nuns who ran the school never taught us that passage concerning Abraham's tackle.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There are a few problems with this question, with the biggest one probably being the assumption that *testify* comes from *testicle* rather than the other way around (as you and David noted in your answers, and I suspected in my comment above). Much of the question unravels if you do away with the assumption that Latin etymology was so strongly influenced by a very specifically Jewish practice.

Comment: This isn't about the English Language. The question title is about social behavior and most of the question focuses on non-English texts that influence current social behavior.

Comment: @BraddSzonye and Mr.Hen My initial reaction was the same, but then I said ... Some questions are far more interesting than their being strictly on or off-topic.  So, I chose to answer rather than a close vote.

Comment: By the way, this Marshall (your "others") is not a source to be taken seriously with respect to linguistics.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, that's only because Italian has simplified _-xt-_ to _-st-_. In Latin, there was no mixing up _text-_ and _test-_, just like there isn't in English.

Comment: The question title seems to have a false premise. You aren't required to swear on a Bible. (Not in [USA Federal court](http://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_603), at least. Although, "**a form designed to impress that duty on the witness’s conscience**" leaves the door strangely open to genital oaths... You know, if the witness is into that sort of thing.)

Comment: @PatrickM - In court, you must either swear or "affirm" that you are telling the truth. You cannot simply refuse. Besides, that's not **really** the issue in this question, is it?

Comment: Oh yes, the oath is still required for witnesses. I was just remarking that you don't have to place your hand on *anything* to swear (or affirm). I would like to think that this is due to the progress of civilization and the realization that the oath itself is more sacred than anything it could be sworn upon. In other words, my feeble answer is "Times have changed."

Comment: *So the servant put his hand under the thigh of his master Abraham and swore...* Did he say, "Aw, bollocks!"? (Sorry...)

Comment: @PatrickM  In Britain you still have to hold the Bible (or the Koran). But you can 'affirm', when, so far as I know you don't hold anything.

Comment: Have the comments been culled? They appear disjointed. Is it just my impression?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think most if not all are here. There have been culls in the comments to the answers, though.

Comment: I'm sure there were more than two comments on 20 March. Yes! The first one, by David M and most upvoted, mentioning a previous edit of yours. And there were others too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - you are probably (it certainly appears so!) correct. It's been a busy week comment-wise; I appear to have lost track. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: The OED is silent on this etymology, and I have read suggestions elsewhere that it may well go in the other direction. In America where 'testify' and 'testimony' are words inherent to the entire legal system, I can understand why this may be of relevance in a feminised society. In Britain it is largely irrelevant since  'testify', and 'testimony' have long since been discarded from both the criminal and civil justice systems. In court we are asked to 'give evidence on oath'. That has been the case for as long as I remember.

Comment: In Trevanian's "Shibumi," the protagonist's Basque friend uses the following formula: "I swear by the four balls of Jesus, Mary and Joseph." [Quotational exactitude not guaranteed.]

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi - that's a (great) new one to me! Thanks.

Comment: @WS2 The Romans would swear oaths on/by [Jupiter Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Stone).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Testo*** an Italian word derives from the Latin term, *textum* (text), which in turn originated from the verb *[texĕre](http://www.finedictionary.com/Textus.html)*, which means to weave.

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/testo/Sinonimi_e_Contrari/), *the* Italian online dictionary and encyclopedia par excellence says:

> **testo**² s. m. [dal lat. *textum* -i o *textus* -us, rispettivam. part.
>   pass. neutro e der. di *texĕre* "tessere"]. [...] **2**. (estens., bibl.) [edizione, spec. se
>   antica e autorevole: t. classici; i t. sacri] ≈ libro, opera, scritto,
>   volume.

Roughly translated, the word *testo* is used when referring to the *classics* i.e. classic literature, and *sacred works* or volumes.

The verb, testify, (In Italian *testimoniare*) derives from the noun, testimony, its Latin form [testimonium](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/testimonio/) which the OP rightly affirmed derives from *testis* and its plural form *teste*.

> The testicle (from Latin *testiculus*, diminutive of testis, meaning
>   "witness" of virility, plural testes)

From Dictionary.com
[**testis**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/testis)

> (pl. testes), 1704, from L. testis "testicle," **usually regarded as a
>   special application of testis "witness"** (see testament), presumably
>   because it "bears witness" to virility (cf. Gk. parastates, lit. "one
>   that stands by;" and Fr. slang témoins, lit. "witnesses").

Looking at the word *teste*, which means <del>also</del> *witness* in Italian, according to Treccani it derived originally from the Latin term, *[tristis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tristis)* (sad, sorrowful, disagreeable or foul smelling) which later evolved into *[terstis](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/teste1/)*, meaning **third party**.

So far I  haven't find any solid evidence that suggests *testament*, *testimony*, *testify*, are directly related to testes/testicles. I'm more inclined to believe that the root word is *textum* meaning  text or *teste* (witness), therefore the tradition of swearing an oath by placing one's hand on the Bible rather than on one's testicles, makes sense. If this needs reminding, Christians are not required to be circumcised, so there is no guarantee the judge would be circumcised. See David M's answer as to why it is relevant.

One more thing to consider, would women really have been asked to place their hands on the judge's genitals before a court of law? Back when?

---

**Edit**

From the Wikipedia article entitled [Sexuality in Ancient Rome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_ancient_Rome#Phallic_sexuality)

> The apparent connection between Latin testes, "testicles," and testis,
>   plural testes, "witness" (the origin of English "testify" and
>   "testimony")[185] may lie in archaic ritual. Some ancient
>   Mediterranean cultures swore binding oaths upon the male genitalia,
>   symbolizing that "the bearing of false witness brings a curse upon not
>   only oneself, but one's house and future line."[186] Latin writers
>   make frequent puns and jokes based on the two meanings of testis:[187]
>   *it took balls to become a legally functioning male citizen*. The
>   English word "testicle" derives from the diminutive testiculum.

link 186 informs

> Joshua T. Katz, "*Testimonia Ritus Italicus: Male Genitalia, Solemn
>   Declarations, and a New Latin Sound Law,*" Harvard Studies in Classical
>   Philology 98 (1998) 183–217 (quotation from p. 193), pointing to the
>   oaths in the Book of Genesis, chapters 24 and 47; **the testicles of
>   ritually slaughtered animals used to affirm testimony in Athenian
>   murder trials**, as at Demosthenes, Contra Aristocratem 23.67f.;
>   Rhetorica ad Herennium 3.33, where ram's testicles are a mnemonic
>   device in a courtroom exercise. Katz proposes that the **[Umbrian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrian_language) hapax
>   *urfeta* means "testicles" and is related to Latin *orbis* (as "balls");
>   thus the Iguvine Tables also make a connection between testicles and
>   "solemn declarations"** (Katz, p. 191).

I had to look up *hapax* because I don't think I have ever come across this word before.  A *hapax legomenon* is a word that occurs only once within a context, either in the written record of an entire language, in the works of an author, or in a single text.

A Slate article, [Where Did We Get Our Oath?](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2004/04/where_did_we_get_our_oath.html) debunks the *urban legend*, as it claims, of ancient Romans who vowed to tell the truth by grabbing hold of their testicles or as I found in one recount;  of two male witnesses who would hold each other's testicles when taking an oath<sup>[Games Primates Play](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/games-primates-play/201112/testify-comes-the-latin-word-testicle)</sup>, I'm inclined to think this version is rather fanciful and at this point we really need an expert in Ancient History.

> Latin scholars have debunked this colorful claim, pointing out that
>   ***testis* more likely comes from the Ancient Greek for "three"—a witness being a third observer of events.**

### Witness  (*Testimonio <sup>[1](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/testimonio/)</sup>/Testimone <sup>[2](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/testimone/)</sup>/Teste <sup>[3](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/teste1/)</sup>*)

Until the 16th century the Italian for *witness* used to be *testimonio* but today that has been superceded by *testimone* and *teste*. A brief history of the word, [testimonianza](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_127.html), written in Italian, is provided by Treccani. *Testimonianza* in English is [deposition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deposition) *(Law) Sworn testimony recorded for use in court at a later date.*

In his book, *AIDS, Bearing Witness, and the Queer Moving Image*, Roger Hallas provides this clear explanation.

[image]

Consequently, it appears that the word, *testify*, and all its derivatives come from the Latin term, *terstis* (third party or person) which Treccani also confirms.

Comment: +1 - good research! lol, Women rarely if ever take oaths in the OT. I think this particular oath was limited to twice in the OT. I will do some additional research to see if I can pin down *testes* to *testiment*.

Comment: Someone like RegDwight, Janus Bahs or tchrist will pin this answer down.

Comment: I also doubt whether a woman's testimony was deemed valid in any case, so where she placed her hands while giving it would not be very relevant... @Susan: I understand what you mean, but please show some consideration when using language like _pinning down testes_ :( Men can be very empathic about those things.

Comment: Thank you for the Italian source, Treccani is valuable. But I'm afraid your answer contains several errors, big (there is no connection with Italian *testo*) and small (*tristis* does not mean "sad, disagreeable" here). There is more.

Comment: @Cerberus I concede that there may be no direct connection with *testo* but for *tristis* I copied the definitions that are in the link (wiktionary)!

Comment: @Cerberus mine was an attempt to unveil an answer. I know I am not brilliant, and I know that my explanations are at times clunky, but I enjoy a challenge, I learnt something new, and I welcome constructive criticism like yours.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: OK cool. (Tristis "sad" is an anachronistic homonym.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: What I mean is that the Proto-Latin/Italic, unattested form **tristis* "third, witness" is not related to its classical homonym *tristis* "sad" (of dubious origin).

Comment: An ingenious approach, but it is unfortunately undermined by the fact that there are many instances of ‘testament’ et al. dating back to times when the sequence _-xt-_ had not yet been simplified to _-st-_. In other languages where they did not coincide, there is also a clear distinction between ‘text’ on the one hand and all the others (testes, testament, head, testify, etc.) on the other.

Comment: @Cerberus, I suppose they could be related—but if so, it would obviously be in the other direction, ‘third’ being the basic meaning and ‘trist’ the secondary. Doesn't seem a particularly compelling link semantically, though, just phonetically plausible. Like you, I highly doubt Treccani has that one right. (I admit I've never heard of Treccani’s dictionary before, so I do not know if it is in general a decent work or not.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Trust me, the Treccani encyclopedia and Italian dictionary is highly esteemed and respected. Not as thorough as the Oxford English Dictionary (its equivalent perhaps) but it is, I repeat, very reputable and reliable.

Comment: @Cerberus What do you make of the etymology behind "teste" here: http://www.etimo.it/?cmd=id&id=18290&md=fafe9384d1defdfe659f08cc4ed30feb I've looked online for *trestem* and *trèstem*  but I can't find anything. The only results I get are either in Czech or Portuguese :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That is an interesting alternative etymology (*tenere*, "hold up"), but you are looking at the 1907 edition of Pianigiani. He based this particular etymology on the works of Froehde and Corrssen, probably from the 19th century. As the website says: *Dopo quasi cent'anni dalla sua comparsa, non si può negare che i segni dell'età si facciano vedere.* The more recent etymological dictionaries, like De Vaan, Walde, Meillet (you can find them in your local academic library or torrent them), all say it comes from **trito-sth2-o-* "third standing by".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'm not sure what you mean? The fact that *tristis* "sad" and **tristis* "third" are most probably unrelated is not contested—not by Treccani, nor by any other serious etymological dictionary. There was just some confusion about the homonyms. They are two different words, the latter unattasted.

Comment: @Cerb, I see now. I hadn't looked at the link before, so Mari-Lou's wording misled me (I thought Treccani was saying that the ‘sad’ word was the origin of ‘third-stander’, hence my initial confusion).

Comment: @Mari-Lou, Umbrian and Oscian are not dialects at the point in time Katz is talking about—they are the two other big Italic languages apart from Latin that have attestations from back then. Neither is anywhere as well known as Latin is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Right, and this was one reason why I criticized the answer...

Comment: I have to say I am disappointed. I was looking forward to reading a detailed thoughtful answer from a qualified expert, such as Janus Bahs, RegDwight, tchrist, @Cerberus etc. I was more interested in the etymology of the word, *testify* et al than whether men *really* swore in a law of court cupping their balls or penises. I concede, I attempted to answer something which is beyond my league, and I have committed minor errors in my answer but all the more reason why someone who is a true linguist should have taken this opportunity to have clarified.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think you were diligent in your research, broader in scope, and have remained open to multiple interpretations. Your answer is very impressive. Thank you.

Comment: @medica wow... I wasn't expecting that, especially after David's edits which did improve his answer notably. Thank you, I suspect there will be a few EL&U users who'll disagree, and a few who think I don't belong here. They're probably right.

Comment: +1.  Brilliant approach on the matter.  I don't know what made you incline towards Italian but that was an impressive linkage.  This complete page was full of knowledge for me including OP.  I couldn't stop myself thanking you for this contribution though.

Answer (score 18):

I think this is a chicken and the egg argument.

The notion that testimony springs forth from the testicles and/or their use as an agent of swearing truth appears spurious.  And, in fact, conceptually the etymology seems to have gone in the opposite direction.

[The concept of testicles from the latin testis seems to come from the gonads being a witness to male virility.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=testis&allowed_in_frame=0)

In addition to the etymonline entry above claiming it groundless, there are multiple online debunks of the practice of swearing on one's testicles being the origin of testify and related words.  [Source](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/site/comments/testify/);
[Source](http://www.skeptive.com/statements/5064); [Source](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-swe1.htm); [Source](http://www.interestingfacts.org/fact/testis-or-testify) - There is a fair sampling of what I've found.  Most of the "sources" linking the origin to the dubious Roman practice do not provide any etymologic sources.

So, it would appear that the shared root of testis, testimony, testify, etc. is based upon the latin meaning to bear witness, and not to swear upon one's testicles.

---

For us Jews, circumcision represents an act which fulfills the covenant with God that was made by Abraham.

> God said to Abraham, "As for you, you shall keep my covenant, you and your offspring after you throughout their generations. This is my covenant, which you shall keep, between me and you and your offspring after you: Every male among you shall be circumcised. You shall circumcise the flesh of your foreskins, and it shall be a sign of the covenant between me and you. Throughout your generations every male among you shall be circumcised when he is eight days old, including the slave born in your house and the one bought with your money from any foreigner who is not of your offspring. Both the slave born in your house and the one bought with your money must be circumcised. So shall my covenant be in your flesh an everlasting covenant. Any uncircumcised male who is not circumcised in the flesh of his foreskin shall be cut off from his people; he has broken my covenant."

There is generally no mention of the testicles in that act.  The testicles have no special meaning in Judaism beyond the obvious as a means of reproduction.  As such, I would disagree with some of the above sources claiming that the practice of placing one's hands under the thighs being a bowdlerization of hands on the *testicles* to be unlikely.

Rather, the placing of the hands over the penis according to some of the rabbinic literature is a reference to this being Abraham's most sacred feature (his penis being the living symbol of his covenant with God due to its circumcision).  Or, it might just be literal that the master sits on the hands of the supplicant.  [Source](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4798).

[Another in depth discussion of this concept can be found here.](http://rexcurry.net/yarek-oath-praying-hands-kneeling-inner-thigh-circumcision.html):

> A popular claim also alleges that Greeks and Romans would touch their own testicles while swearing, however there is no evidence in support.   The "testicle" theory argues that the testicles were used for oaths because they represented virility, power, and represented the man’s future generations, and the source of life. If so, perhaps that is the true "ancient Roman salute" (grasping one's own testicles), as the stiff-armed salute is definitely NOT an "ancient Roman salute."
>
> The new theory asks whether the “inner thigh” posture (the "yarek oath" or "yarek prayer" or "yarek pledge") acknowledged the man’s circumcision.  In Judaism the circumcision is the male’s covenant with God and is also called the “Covenant of Abraham,” because it began with the Patriarch Abraham.  Two references to the “inner thigh” oath (above) refer to Abraham, whose circumcision would have been new and revered.  Abraham would have circumcised his slaves, who later performed “inner thigh” oaths to Abraham.

It stands to reason that others who made similar covenant with God might consider their genitals to be sacred as well.  And, they would be likely to consider it a portable symbol of their connection with God.  (Particularly before the Gutenberg Bible brought the sacred word of God to the common man in a much less intimate form.)

Comment: @DavidM You might want to note in your answer that the etymonline entry for *testis* refutes a folk etymology very similar to the one in the question.

Comment: @BraddSzonye That is the link highlighted, but I will make it clearer.

Comment: Quoting rather than just linking is usually a good idea.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Thanks!  I did as you suggested, or do you think it needs more exposition?

Comment: Oh I see now that you were already taking the debunking-folk-etymology approach to this answer, but somehow I overlooked it. Perhaps be more explicit? Start out with a clearer summary laying out what the etymology is and is not?

Comment: Specifically, it's the third paragraph that is throwing me. It's somehow not coming across that the connection between testicles and literally swearing oaths is folk etymology. I would start out with a simpler and more direct topic sentence (not everyone will get the chicken and egg thing), like “Testicles are named for witnesses, not the other way around. And it's a metaphor, not a reference to an actual oath.” I think that is already in your answer, but it's easy to overlook (at least for mediocre readers like me).

Comment: @BraddSzonye Thanks for your input!  I appreciate the help.  I actually wrote the original post at 1:30 AM . . .

Comment: Yeah I saw it and up voted then, but it's a much better answer now.

Comment: @DavidM - Your first sourced link I found good; the second, not, the third states: *One reason for the confusion may be that swearing on the testicles is recorded in the Bible. The practice is mentioned in the Old Testament, though the King James’ version bowdlerised the reference in Genesis to “grasping the thigh”.* So I think your answer has contradictions in it. My question refers specifically to the Jewish tradition, with a possible toss off to Romans (which was far from the main point.)

Comment: @medica Unfortunately, I think this is a common theme in Old Testament vs. New Testament.  There are many misconstrued notions of Judaic practices.  In many cases there have been mistranslations, misunderstandings, etc.  I presented it as a source because perhaps my own, and the rabbinic interpretations were incorrect.  (I don't believe so, but I presented it for fairness.)  The overarching theme though seems to be that the supposed Roman practice is spurious.  The testicles hold no special religious place for us Jews, so I doubt the validity of the other interpretation.

Comment: @medica As to the second source.  I merely wished to present a sampling of sources.  Not just one.  There were others.  But, I basically presented the first few I had run across.  The first source is the best, though.

Comment: @DavidM - I won't insist, but trust me, I did my homework on my question, and there is no doubt on the parts of *many* commenters, rabbi and theologian alike, that this oath was exactly what I explained, and may well have been alluded to through other bowdlerized oaths. If your answer is *Your assumption is wrong because Jews didn't do that", I can't accept it. Just sayin'.

Comment: @medica I've added a few more sources.  But, logically you have:  two dangly bits without religious significance and a circumcised penis which is a symbol of the covenant with God.  Which one would *you* swear an oath on?  I'm not saying bowdlerized is wrong, I'm saying they bowdlerized the wrong thing!

Comment: Depending on who you ask, that's either masturbation, coitus interruptus, rejection of levirate marriage, or simple disobedience. Assuming that Onan is a real person and not an allegory for the extinction of a clan. But you're correct at least in noting that seed is important to a lot of people. Still, rage weight of evidence seems to point toward “Latin speaking folk didn't actually do this.”

Comment: @medica All I can do is rely upon my experience, and the sources above.  Jews just don't revere testicles.  I'm not sure why.  I'm rather attached to my own. ;-)

Comment: @medica I've derived an inordinate amount of enjoyment from this question!  Fascinating!

Answer (score 4):

In response to the initial question, not the etymology: 
The original post notes that the reason for the practice was incidental and unique to Abraham, and the underlying principle is more generic.

> Since one (a Jew) who swears must take with his hand an article
>   related to a mitzvah

(In fact, I can't think of other options he may have had. There were no other articles related to G-d's commandments, as the remainder of object-related commandments were not given until hundreds of years later.)

The intent is to hold a sacred object to associate the oath with the oath-taker's inviolable beliefs, which is why the Bible is used.

Comment: Can you comment as to testicles vs penis vs hands under thighs?  You seem up on your Midrash. (More so than me.)

Comment: Well, the placement *is* literally under the thigh, but it is clearly a euphemism. On the question of precise placement of the hands (if it were considered important to the essentially symbolic gesture) it seems equally clear  that as the Mitzvah is associated with the foreskin, the testicles don't come into it.

Comment: @medica You asked for more than *my* word that it had nothing to do with testicles... I figured we'd ask a *Yeshiva booker*...  I just wanted clarity that the Milah is in fact not the testicles, because I couldn't prove it to you personally.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually true that ancient Romans swore on their testicles - someone testifying in court would deposit a sum of money, and if the judge or judges concluded that he told the truth, he received his deposit back. If he lied, the money was forfeit to the state. The oaths sworn by soldiers, on the other hand, were for loyalty to the consuls or to the emperor and their very lives could be forfeit if it were deemed broken. These oaths, called *sacramenta* as they were sacred rites, were abhorred by early Christians, possibly for a number of reasons:

1. The only sacraments (not coincidentally, also *sacramenta*) that a Christian may take are those prescribed by the Church.
2. As the oath invoked a pagan deity or demanded unconditional obedience to someone other than Christ, it was inappropriate for Christians.
3. Matthew 5:34-5 enjoins: "But I say to you, do not swear at all: neither by heaven, for it is God's throne, nor by the earth, for it is His footstool; nor by Jerusalem, for it is the city of the great King"; many early Christians (and still some today) interpreted this to forbid oaths of any kind.

The practice of holding your hand on the Bible seems to have originated as kissing the Bible, perhaps as a way to prove the testifier is Christian (and therefore that his testimony is trustworthy), or perhaps to root out witches or heathens.

Regardless, the oldest gesture associated with oath swearing still in wide use today is actually the raised right hand. Psalm 144:8 speaks of "Whose mouth speaks lying words,
And whose right hand is a right hand of falsehood." That means it's been passed down at least from the time of ancient Israel to the present day, over 3000 years.

Comment: relevant sources (a commentary, perhaps) to support your interpretation would br most welcome, especially of your last statement. The right hand of falsehood could be many things.

Comment: The use of a raised and/or right hand as a sign of oath-swearing is common in the Torah/Old Testament, performed by among others Abraham (raised in Gen 14:22) and God (raised in Ex 6:8 and right in Isaiah 62:8) - not that God necessarily has hands, but merely that by or with a raised/right hand is the way in which oaths are made.

Right-handed oath-swearing is also a motif in pagan Greek literature ("the all-powerful right-handed oath" in Euripides) and in descriptions of Egyptian legal practice.

Answer (score 3):

Your *own* testicles are sacred to you; the *judges* testicles are not sacred to *you*. You would therefore place your hand over *your own* testicles, rather than somebody elses.

It is your own nuts that are on the chopping block. You might not care, if they were somebody elses.

I believe that the inference is that one's testicles could be removed, if one breaks the oath. I swear by these! They will be forfeit, if I break my oath. That is how solemn I am. (One could be quite insincere and even jesting, if one said, "Should I be telling a lie, you may remove *the judges* testicles.")

In the same way, one's immortal soul was to be forfeit, when one put one's hand on the Holy Bible.

Comment: You need back up for this one. A reference, a link, anything! But I find myself strongly agreeing with you in your first paragraph.

Comment: +1 - this speaks sense. I think Biblically, they wouldn't suffer loss of the testicles (that was a big deal) but rather a loss of *seed* - their offspring. That was an even bigger deal.

Answer (score -1):

Because the Genitals were the place of Circumcision - and Circumcision was their Covenant with God.  So they were not making an Oath on the Genitals at all, but on the Sign of the "Covenant" that was on their Genitals.  Most people don't understand this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU. This answer is covered well in the above answers., in effect making this answer redundant. It's always a good idea to read the answers given to see if you're adding anything new. Thanks. ')